# Explicitly define form action

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I have a website template developed using html, JavaScript, CSS and JQuery.
There is a file (contact.js) that describes the ajax code for forms as below:

```js
$(function() {    
submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "../submit.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: email
                       }, 
             success: function() {),
             error: function() {},
             })
        },
        });
```

Now, problem is that when I create a custom form and want it to redirect to my own file (not the 'submit.php'), it does not pick the url specified. It automatically takes the ajax url.
Here is my sample code

```html
<form method="POST" action="postcomment.php?parent=<?php echo $blogId ?>" >
```

Is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the `form` action attribute the same way you retreive  `name` and `email`.

In case the action attribute is empty, use `../submit.php`

```
$(function() {    
submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
  event.preventDefault(); 
  // get values from FORM
  var name = $("input#name").val();
  var email = $("input#email").val();
  
  var action = $("form").attr("action");
  var url = (action == "") ? "../submit.php" : action;
  
  $.ajax({
    url: url,  // Use the url variable here
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      name: name,
      phone: email
    }, 
    success: function() {),
      error: function() {},
    })
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks. So, if I want a form to post to e.g. post.php and , all I have to do it edit the code like this: var url = (action == "") ? "../post.php.php" : action;

Comment: If you want to use a specific url, use the `action` attribute of the form: `<form action="../somepage.php">`. If you do not specify an action, like `<form>`, then the "default" url `../submit.php` will be used.